# how to search key in jsonb type column in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a column in PostgreSQL with jsonb datatype. I need to check one key whether it exists in that column or not by executing query.

Answer (score 0):

To find all the rows in a table where the `data` column contains the key `mykey` on the top level, use

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE data ? 'mykey';
```

Comment: I have a JSONB column with such data in it: {"0": 187, "2259": 8, "2259,3457,3424,3399": 6}. As you see, last key is with several numbers separated with comma. I need to right a query to get only records where JSONB column has at lease a comma sign in the key. Something like this.  SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE "jsonbColumnName"  ?|  ','